# How to print(dir(module)) using a variable in Python?

Tags: python

```
import PyQt5
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

print(dir(PyQt5.QtWidgets))
```

That above code runs perfectly. But when I use a variable it gives an error.

```
qw="QtWidgets"
print(dir(PyQt5.qw))
```

**AttributeError: module 'PyQt5' has no attribute 'qw'**.
Is there anyway I can do that? The reason I use variable is because I want a user input to choose what modules to print(dir()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) built-in function will let you look up an attribute by name:

```
qw = "QtWidgets"
print(dir(getattr(PyQt5, qw)))
```